# Using customized AMI in Elastic Beanstalk (Multi-container Docker) via awsebcli

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to find documentation on using a custom multi-container Docker AMI with the `awsebcli` command line tool. Looking through their docs, the most relevant option i've found is the `--platform` argument:

```
-p platform (for example, php, PHP, php5.5, "PHP 5.5", 
             node.js, "64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.7 running PHP 5.5")
```

Is there a way for me to specify an AMI ID here, or is there another configuration option I should use?

[edit]

Additionally, is this something I can specify inside the `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` file?

```
global:
  application_name: bar
  default_ec2_keyname: foo
  default_platform: Multi-container Docker 1.9.1 (Generic)
  default_region: us-east-1
  instance: r3.large
  profile: null
  sc: git
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution that works:

Using a saved configuration, specify the AMI in the autoscaling configuration section under `OptionSettings`:

```
 OptionSettings:
   ...
   aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
     SecurityGroups: ...
     IamInstanceProfile: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
     InstanceType: r3.large
     EC2KeyName: foo
     # ImageId: AMI ID
```